# Avoid rendering comments in HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, rendering

I have a lot of comments in Rails views.

How i can prevent rendering them ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you're asking about Ruby/Rails comments vs HTML comments... Give this a try in your view:

```
<!-- This is an HTML comment and will show up in the HTML source! -->
```

Now try this:

```
<%# This is a comment that won't show up in the HTML source! %>
<%# 
    You can even use this for commenting multiple lines!
    How useful!
%>
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

use =begin and =end to mark the beginning and end of your comment

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do that. You can monkey patch ERB sources, perhaps, but it is a bit nerdy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Rails programmer, but a quick but of Binging brought up this link:
http://blog.brijeshshah.com/strip-tags-in-rails-javascript-and-php/

The approach he's using is one that I've used in the past where you `sanitize` the view's output. `sanitize` being the name of the function you want to use before rendering the view.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of hackish, but you can wrap it in a helper method

In your view:

```
<% comment do %>
  <%= "this won't be executed" %>
  or displayed
<% end %>
```

in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def comment(&block)
    ## you can do something with the block if you want
  end
end
```

Comment: I found this is an excellent solution for temporarily "commenting out" other complex blocks with helpers and other nested # comments. The <%#... %> approach in the other answer (while correct for this question) doesn't cope with complex nested blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use Haml [Comments: -#](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#comments) allow to comment your haml code without them appearing in the generated html.